# Enumerated with default value, but not name

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, enumeration

```
public class Document {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private Long subjectType;

    @Column(name = "markup")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RuleMarkup nonRuleMarkup = RuleMarkup.MANUAL;
}

public enum RuleMarkup {
    MANUAL("manual markup"),
    NO_REQUIRED("markup not required");

    private final String rule;
}
```

how to save in DB the default value by enum not the name `MANUAL` but value 'manual markup'?

`getRule()` doesn't work because it returns `String` type

Comment: You would need a custom `AttributeConverter`.

Comment: Adding to @M.Deinum comment - [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-persisting-enums-in-jpa#converter) should help.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented interface `AttributeConverter`:

```
public class RuleMarkupConverter implements AttributeConverter<RuleMarkup, String>
```

and just marked my fieald as `@Column`.